# Laravel Submit Form without refresh or reload the page

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.7

I have a Laravel 5.7 Project and I have the next question in my mind:

I have a table when I show all the users on my system, and I have a column called Status when I use Active or Inactive...

Well, I have in my Blade a select option where I use the onChange="this.form.submit()", and working fine

My question are, How can I make it to update the Status in my Users table with this select option, without reload/refresh the page and show the new Status in my Table?

Table on Blade

```html
<table class="table table-bordred table-striped" align="center">
        <tr align="center" bgcolor="#999999">
        <td>Usuario</td>
        <td>Correo Electrónico</td>
        <td>País</td>
        <td>Status Actual</td>
            <td>Cambiar Status</td>
    </tr>

@foreach($User as $User1)
        <tr>
    <td>{{$User1->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$User1->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$User1->pais}}</td>
            <td>{{$User1->status}}</td>
    <td>
        <form method="post" action="{{route('HomeController.create')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="#myFormID">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" name="iduser" value="{{$User1->id}}">
            <select name="status" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="">Cambiar Status</option>
                @if($User1->status == "Inactivo")
                <option value="Activo" >Activo</option>
                @endif
                @if($User1->status == "Activo")
                <option value="Inactivo">Inactivo</option>
                @endif
            </select>
        </form>
    </td>
        </tr>
@endforeach

</table>
```

Controller

```html
public function index()
    {
        $User = User::paginate(20);

        return view('home', [

            'User' => $User

        ]);
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $iduser = $request->iduser;
        $status = $request->status;

        $User = User::find($iduser);
        $User->status = $status;
        $User->save();

        $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Status Actualizado Correctamente');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: You should try using js ajax or something like that

Comment: Add `onsubmit="return false;"` to the `<form>` tag to prevent page refresh

Comment: I recommend Vuejs for this scenario. vuejs is better than jquery. if you want implement with vue I can tell you how you can start it. in addition there are many videos in youtube you can get idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax like that

```
$("#your-select-id").change(function(){
$.ajax({ method:"GET", url:"{{route('your-name-route')}}" },data:{status:$(this).val()})
})
```